# Breezejs iterates query with $top twice

Tags: breeze, breeze-sharp

**Breeze v1.5.4 + webapi2**

When I call my method,

```
IQueryable<InvestObjectInfo> InvestObjectInfos(....)
```

like this:

`/DataApi/InvestObjectInfos?$orderby=TreeNode desc,Id&$top=20&treeNodeIds[]=1204&notChanged=false&isOrder=-1&searchString=`

I always get 2 queries in sql trace, first w/o top and the second one with TOP specified.

What can be wrong here?

Comment: There was an issue, fixed in Breeze Server 1.5.5, which caused duplicate queries when  using inlineCount.  This doesn't seem like the same problem, but it might be worth updating just to try it.

Comment: Are you using EF or NH or ???  What database?

Comment: @SteveSchmitt ok! thank you, I'll try updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, updating to 1.5.5 version has resolved the problem.
Thank you @SteveSchmitt